# Visual C++ compiler, errors compiling stdlib.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am trying to compile a file which requires functions included from cmath. I do not believe my code itself to be at fault for causing this error, I suspect the configuration (it persists even with all of the non-include code commented), but have no idea what is going wrong. I am compiling on a Windows host, 64 bit. Other than adding the masm build configuration, I don't believe I've changed any compile settings to non-default, and the problem persists after disabling masm, and by setting the target configuration to 32 bit. Here is my generated output:

```
1>...\VStudio\VC\include\stdlib.h(467): error C2062: type 'long' unexpected
1>...\VStudio\VC\include\stdlib.h(467): error C2062: type 'long' unexpected
1>...\VStudio\VC\include\stdlib.h(467): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>...\VStudio\VC\include\stdlib.h(468): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>...\VStudio\VC\include\stdlib.h(468): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>...\VStudio\VC\include\stdlib.h(471): error C2062: type '__int64' unexpected
1>...\VStudio\VC\include\stdlib.h(471): error C2062: type '__int64' unexpected
1>...\VStudio\VC\include\stdlib.h(471): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>...\VStudio\VC\include\stdlib.h(472): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>...\VStudio\VC\include\stdlib.h(472): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I have found the troublesome line. Contrary to my expectation, the error does occur in the code, and is the fault of a line inherited from a previous version:

```
#define abs(a) ((a)<0? -(a):(a))
```

is responsible for my problems.

Comment: Please show where the code is being included.

Comment: More than that, show us a small complete source file that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time, `#include` system headers before any of your own code.  That way your macros can't mess with the system headers and lead you astray.

Comment: And beware of interactions between `windows.h` and the C++ standard library. Always protect yourself with `#define NOMINMAX`.